# how to choose a sample?

Tags: sampling

I need to review 600 exams with burbles by hand (I have a software to read them all). How many exams do I need to review in order to have 95% of chance of my software is working properly?

I think this problem is very similar with the surveys in the elections when we take only a small sample to have an idea of the entire population (most of the time of more than 90% of certainty)

EDIT

What is an burble exam: [see this](https://www.google.com/search?q=bubble%20exams&sxsrf=ACYBGNSmkw-Xw9sTI-yzEc9_iETlVgb5Mg:1579620984017&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJ44bdgpXnAhUOKK0KHbYPBkwQ_AUoAXoECC8QAw&biw=1280&bih=561#imgrc=_).

The methodology of the software is giving +1 point for a correct answer, -1 for a wrong answer and 0 for a blank answer. The output is how many points the student has basing on this methodology.

So I need to know if I have some mistakes in my programming analysing some samples, but how many?

Comment: @user2974951 it's just that, I have exams and I want to know how many random samples I need to verify?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the topic. What is burbles, how are you reviewing these exams? How is the software reviewing them? What kind of data do you have? What is the output? Mean? Sum? What do you mean by `95% of chance of my software is working properly`? This is unclear. If you have continuous data you will never get the same value, you need some sort of interval.

Comment: ("Burbles" and "bubbles" are different things: birds burble, fish bubble).  Most people would refer to this kind of exam as *multiple choice.*  Your scoring rule suggests you are contemplating a *binary* multiple-choice exam (such as a set of true/false questions).  For your question to be answerable you need to explain what it means for your software to "be working properly:" exactly what aspect of its performance are you measuring?  Individual responses?  Total grades?  Something else?

Comment: @whuber the performance I'm measuring is the individual grades of the students. Yes they are multiple choice exams (true or false).